# Adding custom method to Laravel model causes create() to ignore attributes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, laravel-8

In Laravel 8, I have already had a working `DocumentPdf` resource - at least I was able to create the object using `DocumentPdf::create($attributes)`.

Now I want to create a custom method in the model, a one that will fill the document with `$data` and send it to browser. While it works for existing documents, adding the method broke `create()` in a way that when I send a filled form, I receive a `Illuminate\Database\QueryException`:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'filename' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `document_pdfs` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2020-10-22 02:42:26, 2020-10-22 02:42:26))

It's not a first custom method in the model, but the only breaking one - commenting out the method makes `create()` work again, but then I lose an ability to fill the document.

`app/DocumentPdf.php`:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf;

class DocumentPdf extends Model
{
    // (... some constants, static methods and relations ...)

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * Checks whether the document is active
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isActive()
    {
        return $this->active;
    }

    /**
     * Get full path to the file
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function fullpath()
    {
        return storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->path);
    }

    /**
     * Fill the document and send it to browser
     *
     */
    public function fill(array $data)
    {
        $pdf = new Pdf($this->fullpath());
        $pdf->fillForm($data)
            ->needAppearances()
            ->send(date('YmdHis') . '.pdf');
    }
```

`app/Http/Controllers/DocumentPdfController.php`:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\DocumentPdf;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf;

class DocumentPdfController extends Controller
{
    // (...)

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('documents.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->authorize('create', DocumentPdf::class);

        DocumentPdf::create($this->validateFormAndStoreFile());

        return redirect(route('documents.index'))
            ->with('model-message', 'Document created');
    }

    // (...)

    /**
     * Validate and parse data for storing/updating the resource.
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    protected function validateFormAndStoreFile()
    {
        $form = $this->validateForm();
        $form += $this->storeFile();
        $form += $this->discoverFields($form['path']);
        unset($form['file']);

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Validate data for storing/updating the resource.
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    protected function validateForm()
    {
        return request()->validate([
            'display_name' => 'nullable|max:255',
            'description' => 'nullable',
            'file' => 'required|file|mimes:pdf',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Parse data for storing/updating the resource in database.
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    protected function storeFile()
    {
        $path = request('file')->store('documents');

        $form = [
            'filename' => request('file')->getClientOriginalName(),
            'extension' => request('file')->extension(),
            'size' => request('file')->getSize(),
            'mimetype' => request('file')->getMimeType(null),
            'path' => $path
        ];

        return $form;
    }


    /**
     * Discover PDF file fields.
     * Todo: I feel like it should be handled in DocumentPdf model
     *      but failed to do so due to BadMethodCallException - to be verified
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    protected function discoverFields($filename)
    {
        $pdf = new Pdf(storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename));
        return [
            'fields' => json_encode($pdf->getDataFields()),
        ];
    }
```

How could I define such method not to break existing functionality? I'd like to have it in a model, since in the future I plan to handle other types of documents, e. g. `DocumentXls`, and have a parent abstract class `Document` that'd be handled by `DocumentController`.

Comment: Make sure you use `fillable` or `guarded` for mass assignment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: @parthjani7 it's there, of course! I've added it to the question, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fill` is a Model method that fills the attributes of the Model. You should not override this; change your method name to something else.

`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder@create` creates a new instance of the Model with the data passed, which will call `fill` to fill the attributes for the Model.

Comment: Oh... Of course it works, thanks! I'd vote you up if I could :)
edit: and now I can!